# Vb.net Milliseconds Format

Tags: vb.net

I Got This String:

```
00:00:59,950
```

lets say that i want :
**00:00:59,950** + 100


then the string look like:

**00:01:00,050**

there is a function that can do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) type to handle this:

```
Dim ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
Dim original As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact("00:00:59,950", "hh\:mm\:ss\,fff", ci)
Dim difference As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)

Dim final = original + difference

Dim output as String = final.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\,fff", ci)
```

Comment: there is a exception in this line: Dim original As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:59,950")

Comment: @rogerjanety You may need to use ParseExact and specify a format - one sec, editing.

Comment: there are tow exceptions:
'ParseExact' is not a member of 'System.TimeSpan'.     and the second:        Too many arguments to 'Public ReadOnly Default Property Chars(index As Integer) As Char'.

Comment: @rogerjanety This is for .NET 4 - what version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Dim dateFormat As String = "hh:mm:ss.fffffff" 
    Dim date1 As Date = #00:00:59,950"
    date1.AddMilliseconds(100)
```

UPDATE:

I must've been more tired than I realized yesterday, I apologize for that.. This should do better:

```
    Dim sTime As String = "00:00:59.950"
    Dim dOffset As DateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(sTime)
    dOffset = dOffset.AddMilliseconds(100)

    Dim sDisplayTime As String = dOffset.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff tt")
```

There you'll get the milliseconds in the format you stated in your question.

Comment: 'date1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. 
there are many errors in this code

Comment: Dim dateFormat As String this line is Unnecessary because we dont use it in the code